# Options Request Successful but still getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest

I am making a DELETE request from a Backbone application and am not sure why it fails with the error shown below.

### OPTIONS Header

Here is my OPTIONS header which is a 200 Success

Request:

```
OPTIONS /revenues/674sf6 HTTP/1.1
Host: api2.revparmax.local
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) ....
Access-Control-Request-Headers: token, accept, origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/app/daily/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 May 2013 20:01:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1...
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, TOKEN
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

### DELETE header

But then my delete request fails...

Request:

```
DELETE http://api2.revparmax.local/revenues/674sf6 HTTP/1.1
TOKEN: 00899766786875875674557454
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:3000/app/daily/
Origin: http://localhost:3000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) ....
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

### Error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api2.revparmax.local/revenues/674sf6. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

### Note

Oh - I should mention the model still gets deleted from the server but my problem is the Ajax deferred within my backbone app is all thrown off then because of this error.

Also, my request payload when it fails is [object Object] - could that be causing the problem?

Comment: What does the DELETE *response* look like?

Comment: No response - also PUT & GET requests both work perfectly - I think it has to do with the request payload

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Chrome? If so, then you may have hit the CORS localhost bug. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin).

Comment: Well GET and PUT requests work without a problem. I'm getting around CORS issues as the OPTIONS call is successful and allows localhost:3000 - I think the issue is the payload being an object - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253256/jquery-ajax-setting-processdata-to-false-breaks-my-ajax-request

Comment: issue is with the object you can use this method aswell JSON.stringfy({hello:'world}')