# GET ajax call and params?

Tags: jquery

I need to set params in my ajax call. I've tried:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/gateway',
        data: {'a': 'b'},
        type: 'GET',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        timeout: 30000
    })
```

But this just appends

```
?[object%20Object]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253256/jquery-ajax-setting-processdata-to-false-breaks-my-ajax-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `processData` flag. Remove it and your request will work as expected.

Taken from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (emphasis added):

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be **processed and transformed into a query string**, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

You are setting this flag to false so your `data` attribute is not being transformed into a query string. JavaScript is just passing the string value of that object which is `[object Object]`

Take this code for example:

```
a = {"a":"b"}
String(a) // "[object Object]"
```

In your case, this value is being encoded into a URL string which converts the space character to `%20`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
processData: false
```

It's not processing the object you're giving it; jQuery will do this by default, but you're overriding that functionality and telling it not to.

Comment: You've identified the problem but haven't answered the question.