# JQuery processData Significance

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is setting processData to false in jquery ajax call:

1. Has anything to do with time taken for request to reach from client to server.
2. Prevent the default data manipulation and conversion from an Object format to a suitable url String.

Please Explain its use.

Comment: There's a good comment to a related question that explains this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253256/jquery-ajax-setting-processdata-to-false-breaks-my-ajax-request#comment71576073_6253318