# Problem to recover variable passed by ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a "POST" ajax call to getSegnalazioniMappa.php.
When I try to recover the passed variable I have notice: undefined variable.

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gravita').change(function(){
         var index = document.getElementById("gravita").value;  

         $.ajax({
              method: "POST", 
              data:{index:index},
              url: "getSegnalazioniMappa.php",
              processData: false,
              success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(e) {
                 alert(e.responseText);
              },
              dataType: "JSON"//set to JSON   
         }); 
    });
});
```

This is getSegnalazioniMappa.php

```
<?php
   require('../../../setup/database_connection.php');
   if(isset($_POST['index'])){  //this one is always false
    $index = $_POST['index'];
   }
?>
```

HTML

```
 <select name="gravita" onchange="updateTable(this.value)" style="width: 130px;" class="form-control" id="gravita" required>
        <option value="all" selected>Tutto</option>
        <option value="bassa">Bassa</option>
        <option value="media">Media</option>
        <option value="alta">Alta</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: where you got undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting processData to false in jQuery breaks my AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253256/setting-processdata-to-false-in-jquery-breaks-my-ajax-request)

Comment: when I try to recover $index. So I add the isset, but it's always false

Comment: can you add html code also in question? also give comment on the line when you got undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You got undefined in *error* because you did not get any response from the server. you can see in console.

also where is `onchange="updateTable(this.value)"`  defined ???

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gravita').change(function(){
         var index = $(this).val();  

         $.ajax({
              method: "POST", 
              data:{index:index},
              dataType: "JSON",
              url: "getSegnalazioniMappa.php",
              processData: false,
              success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                 console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                  console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                  console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                  console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                  console.log("error: " + err);
              },
                 
         }); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="gravita"  style="width: 130px;" class="form-control" id="gravita" required>
        <option value="all" selected>Tutto</option>
        <option value="bassa">Bassa</option>
        <option value="media">Media</option>
        <option value="alta">Alta</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: updateTable(this.value) is a function, but it's ok. So, can I fix it? If I want to return a simply JSON with the index value from ajax call.

Comment: just `echo "success"` from server and check.

Comment: How should the .php file be?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code should be like this:-

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['index'])){
    echo $index = $_POST['index'];
   }
?>
```

ajax request should be :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gravita').change(function(){
         var index = document.getElementById("gravita").value;  
         $.ajax({
              method: "POST", 
              data:{index:index},
              url: "getSegnalazioniMappa.php",
              processData: true,
              success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
                 console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(e) {
                 alert(e.responseText);
              },
              dataType: "JSON"//set to JSON   
         }); 
    });
});   
</script>
```

processData should be true.