# Send data from jquery ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a post request from jquery ajax to a ActionResult method as follow :

```
$("#itemTextbox, #itemTextboxNew, #quantity1Textbox").on("keydown", function (e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 120){
   var GetReportLast5SellAndBuyURL="/Trd/SellInvoice/GetReportLast5SellAndBuy";
   itemCode = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetReportLast5SellAndBuyURL,
        data: {ItemCode:itemCode},
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        context: this,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (msg) { ... somethings ...});}
```

And in controller, ActionResult is :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetReportLast5SellAndBuy(string ItemCode)
    { ... somthings ...}
```

But when ActionResult is called " ItemCode " is null... What's wrong with this chapter?

I tried different forms of this recipe, but the problem is still there..

Comment: Have you tried it with quotes? like `data: {"ItemCode": itemCode}` 

Comment: Yes.. I tried this

Comment: Have you verified that itemCode = $(this).val(); returns something and is not already null to begin with?

Comment: Yes.. It has value.. I checked it

Comment: ok last thing I know have you tried data: {'ItemCode='+itemCode}? Since you are trying to pass it as a string to your actionresult.

Comment: Why are you using F9 keycode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*try this:*

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetReportLast5SellAndBuyURL,
        data: JSON.stringify({ItemCode:itemCode}),
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false
    }).done(function (msg) { ... somethings ...});}
```

Comment: The `dataType` option is for specifying what format the response is expected in. It can usually be omitted, jQuery will work it out. It doesn't affect the outgoing data in the request.

Comment: you have to specify datatype. another thing is why you have mentioned context as 'this'. that's invalid. try to add -> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: it must be then your URL. try to update different urls format in your project.

Comment: Yes .. I remove " context:this " and added contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8".. So it's value is true.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just comment   processData:false in your script

```
$("#itemTextbox, #itemTextboxNew, #quantity1Textbox").on("keydown", function (e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 120){
   var GetReportLast5SellAndBuyURL="/Trd/SellInvoice/GetReportLast5SellAndBuy";
   itemCode = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GetReportLast5SellAndBuyURL,
        data: {ItemCode:itemCode},
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        context: this
       // processData: false
    }).done(function (msg) { ... somethings ...});}
```

well explained at [[Setting processData to false in jQuery breaks my AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253256/setting-processdata-to-false-in-jquery-breaks-my-ajax-request#comment71576073_6253318][1])

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#itemTextbox, #itemTextboxNew, #quantity1Textbox").on("keydown", function (e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 120){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Trd/SellInvoice/GetReportLast5SellAndBuy?ItemCode="+$(this).val(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        context: this,
        datatype: "JSON",
        processData: false
    }).done(function (msg) { ... somethings ...});}
    
    
   // OR
    
    $("#itemTextbox, #itemTextboxNew, #quantity1Textbox").on("keydown", function (e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 120){
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Trd/SellInvoice/GetReportLast5SellAndBuy",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify({ItemCode:$(this).val()})
        datatype: "JSON",
        context: this,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (msg) { ... somethings ...});}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is worked but it's not good solution.. thanks

Comment: @Majid821 you can choose one of the above. I gave a working solution.that's it thanks

Comment: Yes.. Thanks to you for your answer